Finding a tangent functional

Let $(E, \lVert \cdot \rVert)$ a normed space over $\Bbb{C}$ . Given $x_0 \in E, K \subset E$ and $f \in E'$, we say that *$f$ is tangent on $K$ at $x_0$ * when $\forall x \in K : Re f(x) \leq Re f(x_0)$ . We call the set $H:= \{x \in E : Re f(x) = Re f(x_0) \}$ the hyperplane tangent at $x_0$ .


If $S^1 = \{ x \in E : \lVert x \rVert = 1 \}$ and $x_0 \in S^1$, there is a functional $f\in E'$ who is tangent on $S^1$ at $x_0$

I am trying to do an excercise of an Functional analysis book but I am getting confuse. My first approach was to think about it when $E = \Bbb{C}$ . In this case, it is well known that the tangent hyperplane is the line $r = \{ x_0 (1 + i t) : t \in \Bbb{R} \}$, but I am getting stuck when finding $f: \Bbb{C} \rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ linear, bounded and such that $r=\{ Re f(x) = Re f(x_0) \}$, so any possible help would be appreciated.

For the general case: find $f$ such that $f(x_0)=1$ and $|f|=1$.
